# Showing that a specific set is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to show that a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is lebesgue measurable.

Let $\lambda$ be a Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and let A = $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]: y < x\}$ be a triangle.

I want to show that $A$ is measurable w.r.t $\lambda$.

I started this problem by trying to approximate the triangle $A$ with rectangles.
This is because we know that the rectangles are contained in our $\mathcal{F}$ and a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable unions and countable intersections.

Let $A_{i}^{n} = \{(x,y^{'}) \in  [0,1]\times[0,1]: x \in [\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}], y^{'}\in[0,\frac{i}{n}]\}$

Let $B_{n} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}^{n}$

Let $A^{'} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}$.

I need to show $A = A^{'}$. I will do this in two parts: 1) $A \subset A^{'}$ and $A^{'} \subset A$. I am having troubles solving the second part. I started off with the definition and need some help

\begin{align}
\omega \in A^{'} 
&\implies \omega \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n} \\
\end{align}
I think I need to use the fact that $B_{n+1} \subset B_{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the intersection of a nested sequence of decreasing sets is equal to the limiting set $B_{\infty} = \{(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]: x \in  \}$ ... .

Comment: The triangle is an open set. So it is  a Borel set and any Borel set is Lebesgue measurable,

Comment: If you know that unions of measurable sets are measurable, then you can argue that the interior of the triangle is measurable because it's open, prove that the two line segment boundaries along each axis are measurable, and then take the union of all three

Comment: I believe the triangle includes 2 sides in the set. Namely the opposite and adjacent sides therefore it is not open. I.e take a point on these sides and you cannot put an $\epsilon$ - ball around it such that this ball is contained in the set.

Comment: @RobBland I think by definition of the lebesgue integral in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the measure of a line is 0

Comment: $S=[0,1]^2$ is closed in $\Bbb R^2$ and $A$ is the intersection of $S$ with the open set $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: y<x\}$ so $A$ is a Borel set.

Comment: @Tomislav A set of measure zero is measurable